# Offline authentication best practices in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I intend to create a Xamarin(.Forms) application, and it has to have authentication: the user should provide a username and password to obtain data.

The problem is that it has to work **offline** as well (meaning it shouldn't rely on a server for the authentication process).

I considered the following so far:

- Storing username and password in Preferences - it is not encrypted, easy to reset, easy to obtain etc.
- Storing username and password in database - it could be encrypted (I presume), easy to reset

What are the best practices? Is there any built-in solution for Xamarin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on your app needs - if you just need to authenticate the user to access some restricted data offline - I suggest you to hash the user name and password, and storing it in the local device (doesn't matter where, it's hashed).

If you need to use the username & password later on for authenticate it with the server, then you should use a secured data like keychain, Xamarin has a built in abstraction for using it, it's called [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth), where you can store your credentials securely.

*note - in jailbroken/rooted devices storing sensitive data is risky, use it with caution.

**Edit** - I have added a working code sample of how to consume and use these services:

1) In your portable project add this interface:

```
public interface ISecuredDataProvider
{
    void Store(string userId, string providerName, IDictionary<string, string> data);

    void Clear(string providerName);

    Dictionary<string, string> Retreive(string providerName);
}
```

2) In your Android project, add this implementation:

```
public class AndroidSecuredDataProvider : ISecuredDataProvider
{
    public void Store(string userId, string providerName, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        Clear(providerName);
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);
        var account = new Account(userId, data);
        accountStore.Save(account, providerName);
    }

    public void Clear(string providerName)
    {
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);
        var accounts = accountStore.FindAccountsForService(providerName);
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            accountStore.Delete(account, providerName);
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Retreive(string providerName)
    {
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);
        var accounts =  accountStore.FindAccountsForService(providerName).FirstOrDefault();

        return (accounts != null) ? accounts.Properties : new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

3) In your iOS project, add this implementation:

```
  public class IOSSecuredDataProvider : ISecuredDataProvider
{
    public void Store(string userId, string providerName, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        Clear(providerName);
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create();
        var account = new Account(userId, data);
        accountStore.Save(account, providerName);
    }

    public void Clear(string providerName)
    {
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create();
        var accounts = accountStore.FindAccountsForService(providerName);
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            accountStore.Delete(account, providerName);
        }   
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Retreive(string providerName)
    {
        var accountStore = AccountStore.Create();
        var accounts = accountStore.FindAccountsForService(providerName).FirstOrDefault();

        return (accounts != null) ? accounts.Properties : new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

4) An example of Usage - after fetching facebook token, we'll store it like this:

`securedDataProvider.Store(user.Id, "FacebookAuth", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FacebookToken", token } });`

Note - I added two layers of data in order to have the first layer to indicate whether the authentication was Facebook/UserName-Password/other.
The 2nd layer was the data itself - i.e facebook token / credentials.

Comment: It looks promising, I have to look further into it. Have you used it? I wonder if I can use only the Store and Retrieve section of it for local authentication without creating the authenticator.

Comment: Yep I'm using it, currently i'm storing tokens from my server in the Xamarin.Auth component.

Comment: One more question: can it be used in Xamarin.Forms or only in Xamarin projects?

Comment: I have created an interface in the portable library named 'ISecuredDataProvider' and the implementation of StoreCredentials and Retreive is done in a specific platform.

Comment: I see, it sounds goods. Is it publicly available for examination (e.g. GitHub)?

Comment: Nope, I'll add here my Implementation.

Comment: I actually encrypt the data I am protecting with the users password as the key. That way, if the password is wrong, decryption fails. If it is correct, encryption succeeds and the user has access to the data. This does however (in my case) require server access in the first place.